# How to fill an existing array from another Iterable object

Tags: scala

Does scala provide any container functions for filling *existing* containers from existing data containers

```
 myarray.fillFrom( myiterable )
```

or

```
 myarray.copyFrom( myiterable )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For arrays you can use the reverse:

```
myiterable.copyToArray(myarray)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `myarray` is indeed an array, you have the `IterableLike.copyToArray` family of functions.

---

If you're using a mutable collection, you can use `append`. From the documentation:

```
scala> val a = LinkedList(1, 2)
a: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList[Int] = LinkedList(1, 2)

scala> val b = LinkedList(1, 2)
b: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList[Int] = LinkedList(1, 2)

scala> a.append(b)
res0: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList[Int] = LinkedList(1, 2, 1, 2)

scala> println(a)
LinkedList(1, 2, 1, 2)
```

---

If you're using an immutable collection, then you cannot append anything to it.

Answer (score -1):

Simply use `myIterable.toArray()`

Comment: I think the whole point of the question is that he does not wish to create a new array but use an existing one.